# Timesheets program with QuickBooks or eBillity integration

Tags: time-management, finance

Our company uses QuickBooks for finance, billing and time tracking. They use the eBillity program for back end integration with QuickBooks. That means workers like me have to use it too even though we have no requirement other than enter time.

If you've had the pleasure, then you know eBillity is an absolute mess. The web program constantly nags and prompts you for things you have not control over (which means all you can do is click `OK`), it throws away time entries, it rearranges entries, it changes your settings without asking, it doen't provide an option to change settings you want to change, it sends useless emails telling you something is wrong (but not what or how to fix it), and they don't fix problems reported through support. The list goes on and on, and nearly everyone in the company has varying levels of dissatisfaction and disgust with using it.

I'm interested in a QuickBooks or eBillity alternative to allow me to enter my timesheets. Here are the criteria:

- Integrates with QuickBooks
- or integrates with eBillity web service
- Allows me to create a weekly timesheet
- Allows me to select *Customer* and *Activity* created in QuickBooks
- Allows me to enter time for the customer and activity (.25 hour increments)
- Allows me to *Save* a timesheet
- Allows me to *Submit* a timesheet

And does not do the dumb things listed under eBillity's annoying behaviors.

What options are available so I can enter my time?

Comment: @Izzy - good point. I was kind of defining them in terms of what I *did not* want. Its now been defined properly (I think).

Comment: Yupp, much better :) I'd suggest you add the targeted OS (I assume it should run on Windows?) – and then we remove our comments. Good hunting!